# What is the use case for Ruby's %q / %Q quoting methods?

Tags: ruby, string, quotes

I've been reading through Thomas' Programming Ruby 1.9 and came upon the alternative delimited single and double-quoting methods (`%q / %Q`). I've known of them from other Ruby language references as well.

```
%q/I'm acting like a single-quoted string/

%Q|"I'm acting like a double-quoted string" --Anonymous|
```

I have not been working with Ruby for long, but I have *never* encountered this quoting method in production code.

Other than the obvious ability to **avoid internally escaping quotes** with backslashes, what are the common use cases for this method of quoting over regular single or double quotes? Are they typically used in single or multiline strings? If used in multiline strings, are they ever favored over HEREDOC strings? Is there a particular Ruby idiom where they're commonly found?

Comment: I thought that *was* the use case. I only use heredocs for multi-line strings.

Comment: Heredocs have the big advantage that you can put the intro inside a chain of code, so that it doesn't break the line of code where it is used, like in `str = <<-TEXT.lines.map(&:strip) ...`

Comment: //I have not been working with Ruby for long, but I have never encountered this quoting method in production code.// This Ruby language feature traces its ancestry back to perl. Therefore, you are more likely to find this used among Rubyists who are also current or former perl developers. 

To find several examples, search for "Perl quotelike operator".

Answer (score 115, accepted):

They're extraordinarily useful for escaping HTML with JavaScript in it where you've already "run out" of quoting methods:

```
link = %q[<a href="javascript:method('call')">link</a>]
```

I've also found them to be very useful when working with multi-line SQL statements:

```
execute(%Q[
  INSERT INTO table_a (column_a)
    SELECT value
      FROM table_b
      WHERE key='value'
])
```

The advantage there is you don't need to pay attention to the type of quoting used within your query. It will work with either single, double, or both. They're also a lot less fuss than the HEREDOC style method.

Ruby provides other convenience methods like this such as `%r` which can construct regular expressions. That avoids slash-itis when trying to write one that handles stuff like `http://` that would otherwise have to be escaped.

Comment: The JavaScript example I hadn't considered - where the function of the internal quoting is syntactically significant and it becomes confusing which context (the markup attribute, the JS string, or the whole outer string) is currently being quoted and escaped.

Comment: The HEREDOC style is okay when declaring a variable, but extremely ugly when used as an argument to a method, *especially* when you're trying to supply two of them as different arguments. They're quite confusing to the uninitiated.

Answer (score 12):

#### Overview

Apart from "avoid internally escaping quotes" and the examples previously provided by @tadman there are other use-cases as well:

- auto-generating code in the same language as the generator itself (e.g., Ruby generating Ruby)
- providing cleanly-formatted code that does not confuse the syntax-highlighting feature of your text editor
- allow storage of codeblocks that may have to pass through multiple storage layers (such as a database interacting with a website, or a snippets management system interacting with a text editor, which interacts with a subshell, and so forth)

#### Details

This approach is a general-purpose and robust idiom that works well with any kind of tool that does automated code generation, including but not limited to tools that write boilerplate code in other languages, or tools that manage code snippets for an IDE or text editor.

Besides the examples already provided by @tadman, there is the general case of generating code where the code being generated is the same or substantially similar syntax as the code of the generating program.

In these cases, the solution does a lot more than help with avoiding the use of backslashes to escape quotes. Without a solution like this, there are cases where the generated code can get extremely difficult to maintain.

To see examples of this, feel free to take a look at the following references.

#### References

[ See e.g.,

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuineProgram
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Delimiter_collision
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

]

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I have used them in production when calling a [system](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/system) command and wanting to interpolate some values, like so:

```
 system(%Q(ffmpeg -y -i "#{input_filepath}" -qscale:a 2 "#{output_filepath}"))
```

Super handy.

Answer (score 3):

Its perhaps worth noting that %q is used by bundler and jeweler by default when generating gemspecs, for the summary/description section of the gemspec. This prevents someone from using quotes in the summary or description and breaking the gemspec.

Answer (score -1):

They are useful when your string contains single- or double- quotes. This doesn't happen all that often, but the technique is very useful when it does.

Comment: The op said he wants to know other than "avoid internally escaping quotes".