# Meaning of # symbol

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax

My code has a `#` symbol in the `class_eval` section. This is foreign to me, what does it mean?

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s # make sure it's a string
    attr_reader attr_name # create the attribute's getter
    attr_reader attr_name+"_history" # create bar_history getter
    class_eval %Q{
def #{attr_name}=(attr_name)
@#{attr_name} = attr_name
@#{attr_name}_history = [nil] if @#{attr_name}_history.nil?
@#{attr_name}_history << attr_name
end
}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def #{attr_name}=(attr_name)
@#{attr_name} = attr_name
@#{attr_name}_history = [nil] if @#{attr_name}_history.nil?
@#{attr_name}_history << attr_name
end
```

If `attr_name` variable where equal to, let's say, `"params"`. This would actually transform into this:

```
def params=(attr_name)
@params = attr_name
@params_history = [nil] if @params_history.nil?
@params_history << attr_name
end
```

Why that happens? Because of something called String interpolation. If you write `#{something}` inside a String, `something` will be evaluated and replaced inside that String.

And why whould the above code work even though it's not in a String?

The answer is, because it is!

Ruby gives you different ways to do things, and there is an alternative syntax for some literals, that goes like that: `%w{one two three}` where `{}` could be any delimiter, as long as you use the same or the corresponding closing one. So it could be `%w\one two three\` or `%w[one two three]`, they would all work.

That one, `%w` is for Arrays, `%Q` is for double-quoted String. If you wanna see all of them, I suggest you take a look at this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html

Now, in that code

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s # make sure it's a string
    attr_reader attr_name # create the attribute's getter
    attr_reader attr_name+"_history" # create bar_history getter
    class_eval %Q{ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< # STRING BEGINS
def #{attr_name}=(attr_name)
@#{attr_name} = attr_name
@#{attr_name}_history = [nil] if @#{attr_name}_history.nil?
@#{attr_name}_history << attr_name
end
} <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< # STRING ENDS
  end
end
```

We can see the whole part with the String interpolation is inside a `%Q{ }`. That means the entire block is a big double-quoted String. And that's why the String interpolation will successfully do it's job before sending the String to eval.

Comment: No prob, mate. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is called string interpolation. What it effectively does is it substitutes `#{attr_name}` with `attr_name` actual value. The code you posted shows one of the use cases - when you want to use variables with generic names in runtime.

Then use case used even more often is the following:

You can use string this way: `"Hello, #{name}!"` and `#{name}` will be automatically replaced here - this is very handy feature.  A syntactic sugar.

But note `%Q` in the code - this transforms the following code to a string and is later passed to `class_eval` and is executed there. See more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144543/what-is-the-use-case-for-rubys-q-q-quoting-methods). Without it it wouldn't work, of course.

Comment: Worth mentioning what `%Q` is doing too I think, because if it's missed the remaining code just looks like weird Ruby where interpolation can occur anywhere, which may be a point of confusion

Answer (score 2):

> why the next code has got # in class_eval?

this is string interpolation.

one example:

```
x = 12
puts %Q{ the numer is #{x} }
# >>  the numer is 12
```

> %Q [Here](http://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/)
>
> This is an alternative for double-quoted strings, when you have more quote characters in a string.Instead of putting backslashes in front of them.