# How can I individually quote words in a string separated by pipe characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, split, escaping

My params hash contains string value like:

```
маслёнка | масло
```

My method currently has this code:

```
s = %Q{(@content "#{params[:structure]}")}
```

This quotes the whole string:

```
(@content "маслёнка | масло")
```

but I need each element quoted separately like this:

```
(@content "маслёнка" | "масло")
```

I know I need to split my params string to substring via the `|` symbol, but the elements need to be individually quoted and separated by a pipe character. How can I do that here?

Comment: This smells like an X/Y problem. What do you *really* want to do with this string, and why are you doing complex escapes/quoting in your controller?

Comment: @CodeGnome need this for sphinx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.split(" | ").map {|s| "\"" + s + "\""}.compact.join(" | ")
```

will get you what you want.

Comment: Also see [discussion on %q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144543/what-is-the-use-case-for-rubys-q-q-quoting-methods).

Comment: also i could set param without | just with space

Comment: Whatever you want. I interpreted this as answering your original question: "word1 | word2" -> "\"word1\" | \"word2\"". If you don't need/want the pipe, just change the `join` at the end. If you mean `params[:structure]` could come without the |'s, just make a check and change the `split`.

Answer (score 1):

### Quote Your Array Elements After Splitting

Your issues is caused by the complexity of your quoting requirements. One way to resolve this is to use [Kernel#sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) and Ruby's alternate double-quote literals (`%Q`) to build your string. For example:

```
s = sprintf '(@content %s)',
            params[:structure].split( /\s+\|\s+/ ).
            map { |elem| %Q["#{elem}"] }.
            join(" | ")
# => "(@content \"маслёнка\" | \"масло\")"
```

You can verify that the string is properly escaped with [Kernel#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts), which in this case yields:

> (@content "маслёнка" | "масло")

Answer (score 0):

This will split the `params` hash into strings separated by `|`, but will not retain the actual `|` character.

`s = %Q{(@content "#{params[:structure].split('|')}")}`

Comment: i could set param without | just with space

Comment: If I understood the original question correctly, you are trying to split the string separated by '|'. You can split it by whitespace as well by changing the split argument to .split(' ')

Comment: split: yes... but also turn all this splitted values in "" and set | betwen them