# Why use %q( ) or %( )?

Tags: ruby, string

As I am going through some of the Ruby Doc's I have encountered percent strings, two of which I am a little confused about. Specifically it is the %()

```
string = %(I am a string)
 #=> "I am a string"
```

and the %q()

```
 string = %q(I am a string)
     #=> "I am a string"
```

When I played with them they both seem to output a string the same as if I just wrote

```
string = "I am a string"
#=> "I am a string"
```

Why, and in what instances, would one prefer to use them as opposed to just creating a string literal, since they do not seem to save much by way of typing nor ease?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144543/what-is-the-use-case-for-rubys-q-q-quoting-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%` and `%q` forms *are* string literals as well, just with different parsing rules. Consider:

```
%q(I am a 'string' with a "string" in me!)
```

Allowing the different forms, with different escape/termination characters, can make *certain* literals easier to express. I prefer `'`-by-default, but it's about using an appropriate form for the given situation.

The `%` (same as `%Q`) and `%q` forms have the same relationship as the `"` and `'` forms; so the difference between using one or the other (of the same family) should be clear.

Historically, these [different % Notations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) were 'borrowed' from perl.

Comment: That clears it up a little for me and thanks for the link..very useful!